# Azure Data Factory runtime looks different when running Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying Azure Data Factory V2. I run a DB extract and sink output into Blob. When I use DataFlow the resulting files are split in parts like in Spark output style. This is because a Spark cluster is the runtime (i assume). However when I run a "normal" pipeline (no Dataflow) then it seems output is different e.g. output can even be a single file. So my question is: is there runtime difference between pipeline and dataflow? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you are seeing is the Copy Activity infrastructure vs. the Data Flow activity infrastructure.

Copy is built for fast data movement while Data Flows is built for scale-out data transformation.

The diagram in the data flow overview document may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview

Comment: thnaks. I understood Data Flow runs on Spark. But is Copy Activity then just normal execution runtime?

Comment: Copy Activity shares configuration information with data flows from the Azure Integration Runtime. Copy Activity also supports self-hosted IR, which is not supported in Data Flows.